# nodejs http post request instagram follow/unfollow

Tags: node.js, http, request, xmlhttprequest

I have a script that uses cookies to make instagram post requests.
Problem: My follow requests dont work but my unfollow does

Works (statuscode = 200)

```
var url = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/19237590/unfollow/';
```

Doesnt Work (statuscode = 302)

```
var url = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/19237590/follow/';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a status code of 302 is a redirect, it should provide another URL in a location header. e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Connection: keep-alive
Server: meinheld/0.6.1
Date: Sat, 27 Jan 2018 10:51:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://example.com
```

You can then follow this..
If you want to try this out on another URl try:
    https://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F

Comment: So, I've been testing this script for like 2 weeks now trying to get it to work and understand it. Usually when there was a statuscode 302 it meant that one of the headers or cookies was wrong for the unfollow thing.

Comment: The location in the headers is www.instagram.com/nhl/ which is the person I am attempting to follow